# Why does this code print "olleH"?

Tags: c++, recursion

Why does this program print "olleH"?

It seems like it this program would print quite literally nothing - but I seem to not understand how recursion works.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void function(string, int, int);

int main()
{
    string mystr = "Hello";
    cout << mystr << endl;
    function(mystr, 0, mystr.size());

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void function(string str, int pos, int size)
{
    if (pos < size)
    {
        cout << str[pos];
        function(str, pos + 1, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: It does return nothing, because the return type is `void`.

Comment: Trace through the code. I have faith in you.

Comment: There is no "cout statement" in the code. Even if there were, one or two, they don't "return" anything, either.

Comment: Why did you expect it to print "quite literally nothing"?

Comment: Also, this should print Hello. Not olleH.

Comment: No one is making fun of you. They are downvoting because you have not made sufficient effort to solve yourself.  strp through the code in your debugger

Comment: Cannot reproduce. This program prints `Hello` twice. http://ideone.com/Mmw23o

Answer (score 2):

Two things: Firstly, terminology: the function declaration you've written returns `void` and not `string`, but does indeed print a string. Secondly, the code as you have posted it prints "Hello" when I run it. I'm going to assume your question pertains as to why "olleH" is printed if you switch the order of these two lines in `function()`:

```
cout << str[pos]; //prints "Hello"
function(str, pos + 1, size);
```

compared to:

```
function(str, pos + 1, size);//prints "olleH"
cout << str[pos];
```

This, as you've stated, is recursion. To understand this, you need to keep in mind the order in which the functions are called and the reverse order in which they return, passing control to the function that called them. The first call to `function()` with `pos` at the beginning of the string returns last, and the recursive calls return before it does, with the innermost function call with `pos` at the end of the string being the first to completely run. (This is because the recursive call is only made `if (pos < size)` and this limiting is very important in preventing an infinite loop). So in the first call to `function()` with `pos` at the beginning, if it writes the first character before calling `function()` again to write the rest of the string, then the string will be in order. If you write the first character after the rest of the string is written, then it will be in reverse order, as in the two different cases.